# Mark 1:41 - Was Jesus indignant or compassionate?

Tags: exegesis, bible-translation, gospel-of-mark, textual-criticism, niv

http://biblehub.com/mark/1-41.htm

> **New International Version**
>   Jesus was indignant. He reached out his hand and touched the man. "I am willing," he said. "Be clean!"
> **New Living Translation**
>   Moved with compassion, Jesus reached out and touched him. "I am willing," he said. "Be healed!"
> **English Standard Version**
> Moved with pity, he stretched out his hand and touched him and said to him, “I will; be clean.”
> *(...)*
> **King James Bible**
> And Jesus, moved with compassion, put forth his hand, and touched him, and saith unto him, I will; be thou clean.
> *(...)*
> **Jubilee Bible 2000**
>   And Jesus, having mercy on him, put forth his hand and touched him and said unto him, I will; be thou clean.
> *(...)*
> **Young's Literal Translation**
> And Jesus having been moved with compassion, having stretched forth the hand, touched him, and saith to him, 'I will; be thou cleansed;'

Yesterday, we had two guys at a table note that their translations of Mark 1:41 said very different things. One guy said that his translation said that Jesus was "moved with compassion," while the other guy's translation said that Jesus was "indignant."

The puzzling thing is that both guys were reading an NIV. The one that said "moved with compassion" was the 1978 version, but the other was an ebook that the guy didn't know how to check the year of but I'm guessing is newer than 1978 since it's an ebook.

Looking at the above link, a lot of the translations (including a literal translation) say "compassion," "mercy" or "pity," which are all similar ideas, but only the NIV says Jesus was "indignant." We discussed this for a while and decided it makes more sense for Jesus to feel compassion than anger in this context, considering the way he reacts to similar situations elsewhere.

Is there a story behind why modern NIV translations say something completely different from the older ones, and different from all these other translations?

Comment: Here's a good overview of the issue: https://billmounce.com/blog/little-text-criticism-mark-1-41

Comment: This is probably better as a Biblical Hermeneutics question, and indeed, it's been asked (and answered) there: [Was Jesus angry and if so why in Mark 1:41?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/11667/9713)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on BH.